# Can a stone resin floating sink be cut down to become an undermount sink?

Tags: plumbing, sink

I originally purchased this sink to sit atop a counter for a bathroom. When you look at the photos you'll see it can be a standalone sink with exposed plumbing underneath but I was going to set it on top of a counter. After a lot of pushback from my roommates who want more flat counter space to be able to set bathroom related objects on I wanted to see if I could save this sink and make it an undermount sink. This way when we have our quartz countertop fitted (nothing has been installed or cut yet) the sink in the photos at link below will be expoxied underneath and there will be more flat space on the counter to work with. To create this, I would have to cut all around the basin where the "ramps" on either side go down toward the drain that's basically a slit. I would leave about an inch or so all round to have this as the area to adhere to the underside of the quartz counter.

[https://www.houzz.com/products/modern-wall-mounted-rectangular-stone-resin-v-shaped-sink-matte-white-prvw-vr~156422646](https://www.houzz.com/products/modern-wall-mounted-rectangular-stone-resin-v-shaped-sink-matte-white-prvw-vr%7E156422646)

Would this be possible? Or would my efforts just result in chipping, cracking and destroying the sink? We asked our general contractor and he said "No, sorry." But I wonder if he was being genuine or is just tired of our ongoing changes and snags in our remodeling projects.

Comment: would not be easier to lover the sink into cabinet

Comment: @ Ruskers. No, it would not. The ends of the sink as is would not fit into the cabinet. It's way to wide. It would need to be cut to do my idea.

Comment: measure the inside of the cabinet and measure the top plate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's stone and resin, it can probably be cut reasonably easily with a diamond wheel.

You're going to void any warranty

You're not going to have manufacturer support for your proposed usage so either you or your contractor is going to be left guessing when it comes to attachment methods etc....

Can it be done well?  Almost certainly.

Will it be done well?  It's impossible to say.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the side view- I would not cut that.

The cutting it self is not the problem, it can be done.

If you cut along the rim, the whole unit will loose the form stability.

You will stil have to cut a hole in the counter top.

[image: sink]

There is another option to consider

Lover it in to cabinet to it becomes recessed in, even with cabinet surface.

Someone will have to cut a precise hole in the cabinet top.

Comment: @ Ruskes - would you explain why it can't be done? I just took a photo of the underside of my sink. If I can cut this sink without damaging the material I can leave a 1" flat edge that could be expoxied to the underside of the quartz countertop.      <a href="https://ibb.co/2qYfj4F"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/0qVdfbn/20220609-203542.jpg" alt="20220609-203542" border="0"></a> Also. I can't lower the sink into the cabinet. The lower cabinet consists of three cabinets with the one in the center being narrower than the width of the floating sink intact.

Comment: OK, you can try to sell it, or get a diamond cutter and cut it. However cutting the granite top is a different story. I think that cutting the frame will make the whole unit unstble.

Comment: It will be quartz, not granite. It's not uncommon to custom cut square or circular holes to undermount sinks. I don't even know why you're mentioning that. Mine will simply be a custom size since the V-shaped sink is 25" wide by 13" from front to back.

Comment: @Adrien You already upvoted the other answer, so go with it. Are you cutting it ?

Comment: I'm going to try and cut it. Wish me luck so I don't waste $300 on this sink.

Comment: @Adrien your question was answered by Jasen who says it is a pice of cake. But I WHISH YOU LUCK ! Before you do anything talk to the room mate